# play-json: mapping a json string to nested case class

Tags: scala, play-json

I have a usecase where incoming json string doesn't have a structure similar to the case class.
I have following case classes:

```
case class Parent(children: Seq[Child])
case class Child(name: Option[String], age: Option[Int])
```

User inputs in Parent field as:

```
John:20, Peter:12
```

Incoming json is as:

```
{"parent":{"parent":"John:20, Peter:12"},....}
```

Is it possible I write json formatter to map this to the Parent case class with nested Child list, using play framework json API?

Comment: Yep, you just need to define a custom `Reads[Parent]`. Read [Play Json docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) here.

Comment: If that's really the JSON input you are receiving it will require a bit of work. I would recommend asking for a more normalized format as input.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this is a not a normal json structure.